# If $f \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)$ has $\sum_{j=1}^n \xi_j \hat{f}(\xi) \in L^2$, does that imply that $f \in H^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$?

Tags: real-analysis, sobolev-spaces, fourier-transform

Let $f \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$. For a function $h \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$, let $\hat{h}$ denotes it Fourier transform. Suppose that it is known that the function 
$$g(\xi) = \sum_{j=1}^n \xi_j \hat{f}(\xi)$$

belongs to $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

> I would like to know whether it is true that each function $\xi_j \hat{f}(\xi)$ belongs to $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

Conceptually, this propostion is asking whether $f$ having a combination of all of its distributional derivatives in $L^2$ implies that $f \in H^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

My attempt so far rests on establishing an inequality of the form 
$$|\xi_k| \le C \left|\sum_{j =1}^n \xi_j \right|, \qquad k =1 ,\dots , n,$$

for some $C > 0$. This will then say that $\|\xi_k \hat{f}\|_{L^2} \le C \|g\|_{L^2}$, and this is the conclusion I want. But so far I am stuck. Could it be that the proposition is not true?

Hints or solutions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is $f$ scalar or vector valued? Do you mean by distributional divergence in $L^2$ that $\sum_i f_{x_i}\in L^2(\mathbb R)$?

Comment: @daw--I take $f$ to be scalar valued. I see now that calling $\sum_i f_{x_i}$ a distributional divergence is somewhat confusing and unconventional, since $f$ is not a vector. I will edit the question for clarity.

Comment: @JZShapiro Now I understand the question, in fact I was not sure I understood. I delete the answer

Comment: The operator corresponding to $\sum_{j = 1}^n \xi_j \hat{f}(\xi)$ is the partial differentiation $f \mapsto \sum_{j = 1}^n \partial_j f$. This is the action by one single vector field, and $f$ can be highly irregular in directions orthogonal to the vector field.

Answer (score 1):

The desired result does not hold.

By performing an orthogonal transformation of $\mathbb{R}^n$, your hypothesis is equivalent to asking whether

$$ g\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n) \wedge \partial_{x^1} g \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n) \implies g \in H^1(\mathbb{R}^n) $$

which is clearly false.

---

For an explicit counter example: Let $n = 2$. Let $\chi$ be the characteristic function of the set $[-1,1]\subset \mathbb{R}$ and let $\eta$ be any smooth bump function. Take

$$ f(x_1,x_2) = \chi(x_1 - x_2) \eta(x_1+x_2) $$

then you can check that $f\in L^2$, and $(\xi_1 + \xi_2) \hat{f} \in L^2$, but $f\not\in H^1$.